# Does Thread.sleep() stops calling threads run method?

Tags: java, multithreading, execution, thread-sleep

Can someone please explain to me what I am missing: when I call `Thread.sleep(1000)` I suppose both threads should be executed in 1s so after that why should I make `doSlice` false to stop threads in 1s
why `Thread.sleep()` just doesn't stop them in 1s. I mean after 1s run method even shouldn't be called to check while condition:

```
public class ExecutionScheduling  extends Thread{
    public int slice_count=0;
    public boolean doSlice=true;
    public String name;

    public ExecutionScheduling(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (doSlice) {
            slice_count++;
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutionScheduling executionScheduling=new ExecutionScheduling("ex");
        ExecutionScheduling executionScheduling1=new ExecutionScheduling("ex1");

        executionScheduling.start();
        executionScheduling1.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        executionScheduling.doSlice=false;
        executionScheduling1.doSlice=false;

        System.out.println("ex: "+executionScheduling.slice_count);
        System.out.println("ex1: "+executionScheduling1.slice_count);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread.sleep(1000)` does not _do_ anything at all: It does nothing at all for one full second, and then it returns.

Comment: In addition, the code is not thread-safe.

Comment: I get that so the main thread does nothing for 1s and two chid threads continue running after that when doSlice changes to false child threads will be stoped.

Comment: In order to guarantee that a doSlice change is observed by other threads you should  make it volatile. Otherwise JVM can easily treat that loop as endless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me what I am missing

What you are missing is [memory synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) between the threads.  When you start your 2 background threads, they have their own local memory (on their own CPUs) and you need to specifically update any shared data between them.

What is complicating the code is that `System.out.println(...)` is a synchronized method so it is giving you some memory synchronization "for free" but you shouldn't depend on it (see below).  This means that if you removed that debug code, your program is going to be behave differently.  Be careful of any usage of `System.out.print*` in threaded code.

> ```
> Thread.sleep(1000);
> ```

When you run this sleep command, it will cause the main thread to go to sleep but the 2 background threads continue to run.  They are each updating their own copy of `slice_count` but there is no guarantee that the main thread will see these updates.

```
// need to add the volatile keyword here
private volatile int slice_count;
```

By adding the [`volatile` Java keyword](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html) to `slice_count`, this marks the field as being accessed by multiple threads.   When the main thread the accesses `slice_count`, it will read the most updated value of it.  You might also want to look into `AtomicInteger` which wraps a `volatile int` but allows multiple threads to do stuff like `incrementAndGet()`.

Another place where you have memory sync issues is:

```
executionScheduling.doSlice = false;
executionScheduling1.doSlice = false;
```

So the `doSlice` field also needs to be `volatile`:

```
// need to add the volatile keyword here
public volatile boolean doSlice = true;
```

And lastly, in no order:

- Your fields should be `private` if at all possible.
- It should be `executionScheduling1` and `executionScheduling2`.
- It is a better pattern to define a `Runnable` instead of a `Thread`.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/541527/179850
- You might consider doing a `join()` to wait or each of the threads to finish their work before you print out their results.

  ```
  // set the doSlices to false
  executionScheduling.join()
  executionScheduling1.join()
  // printf results
  ```

  If you add the `join()` calls then this will handle the memory synchronization for you in terms of `slice_count` so those no longer need to be `volatile` as long as you access them *after* the `join()` calls finish.  Yes this is confusing.  Thread coding is non-trivial.  You will still need the `doSlice` fields to be `volatile` because they are accessed *before* `join()` finishes.

Comment: This. Great answer. Plus, @saba: grabbing a good book on Java concurrency (which is far from trivial) is a good start. Reading e.g. Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz is heplful, and getting knowledge on Java's memory model is also a good thing to do. A good point to start is Rafael Winterhalter's presentation - The Java Memory Model for Practitioners available on YouTube.